# Install python3-tk on pythonanywere

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to run a script using turtle module on pythonanywere.com, however, got stuck at an error that cannot find the module named "**tkinter**" and I need to install python3-tk package. I followed this tutorial  [installing new modules on pythonanywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/) in attempt to install the package in Bash console on pythonanywere.com by running `pip3.5 install --user package3-tk`. 
However, I got the error that "could not find the version that satisfies the requirement package3-tk".

I also tried to replace the package name with `tkinter` with no luck either.

Comment: one google search and a couple clicks is all it takes to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the tkinter module from a server such as pythonanywhere. It needs to have a connection to a display and not just a browser window.

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/360/

Answer (score 1):

Just learnt the lesson of finding answer by asking question in different way. My purpose is to use turtle module on pythonanywere, which is not possible as explained in the answer above. However, I just found out that pythonanywhere has an affiliate website that is free and supports turtle ([www.trinker.io](http://www.trinker.io))

Comment: Just a quick note from a PythonAnywhere dev -- I think the site you meant was https://trinket.io/ -- they're not an affiliate, just another site that we think is an excellent resource for people who want to use turtle.